# VSCode not detecting Python Virtual Environment on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

VS Code refuses to use the virtual environment on my Mac.
I believe it has to do with the fact that Python doesn't get added directly to the venv but as a shortcut instead.

[image]

How can I make it so VSCode recognizes my virtual environment?

Answer (score 1):

After about 50 times of trying this, it finally worked.

"python.pythonPath": "env/venv/bin/python3.9"

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to open the project folder on the same workspace. Than, worked.
Example:
I had:
folderProject/app/venv. When I open the folder project and try load venv, it doen´t work. But with I open app as my workspace and venv inside app folder everything work,